# Autohotkey Return to regular function of Spacebar after mapping

Tags: autohotkey

i am trying to be able to toggle between different functions mapped to the spacebar
mapping spacebar isnt difficult, but how the hell do i get the "regular" function of spacebar back ?
Space::Space isnt working XD

```html
BackSpace::tog()

tog()
{
    static togstate = 0
    if (togstate = 1)
    {
        ToolTip, Spacebar Normal
  SetTimer, RemoveToolTip, 1500
  Space::
        togstate = 0
    }
    else
    {
        ToolTip, Spacebar Alternativ
  SetTimer, RemoveToolTip, 1500
  Space::
  {
   SetKeyDelay,5, 10
   Send, 2345
  }
  return
        togstate = 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit: and i just realised, that binding space doesnt work inside funktions... great ^^

Answer (score 0):

1. Ordinary hotkey bindings are more like declarations than commands or functions. So, they need to be on the global level.
2. You just need to use the [`Hotkey`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Hotkey.htm) command, either inside or outside of functions.

Example:

```
Hotkey Space, funcA
Hotkey Space, funcB
Hotkey Space, Off

funcA() {
    ...
}

funcB() {
    ...
}
```